# Can ところで be used with statements as well?

Tags: word-choice, words

Many Japanese-English dictionaries define "ところで" as something similar to "by the way" or "incidentally", but is it also used with statement-type sentences as well? If not, what would be the most appropriate phrase to use?

I am looking to say something along the lines of:

> By the way, I ran into Alan at Starbucks the other day.

Here are some of the examples I have seen listed, but I am having trouble finding examples that are not questions.

1. > ところで例の件はどうなりましたか。
2. > ところで、今日はおひまですか
3. > ところでよ、そのおめーのおとうさんはどこにいんのさ？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「ところで」 is used to make statements all the time.  There is nothing strange or unnatural about it.

To borrow your own example, you could easily say:

> 「ところで、この前{まえ}スターバックスでばったりアランに会{あ}ったよ。」

In more casual conversations, you might hear us use 「それはそうと」、「あっ、そうそう」, etc. instead of 「ところで」, but that is ***not*** to say that 「ところで」 sounds very formal.

ところで、なかなかいい質問{しつもん}をしますね。

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer! I really appreciate it.